# Writing a MySQL wrapper around CRC32

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions, typing

I need to write some cross-vendor SQL queries, and I would like to hide certain details that are of lesser importance in the context.

Namely, I want to create a wrapper named `checksum()` around the MySQL function `crc32()`. It would just passes its argument to `crc32()` and returns the result of the latter function.

```
mysql> select crc32('foobar');
+-----------------+
| crc32('foobar') |
+-----------------+
|      2666930069 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION checksum(x TEXT) RETURNS BIGINT DETERMINISTIC
    -> RETURN crc32(x);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select checksum('foobar');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('foobar')' at line 1
```

I am not convinced this is an actual syntax error. I am suspecting a type mismatch, but I have tried with all types I could think of (`VARCHAR(255)` for `x`, `UNSIGNED INT`, `LONG`, etc. for the return type).

I have no more ideas, and ChatGPT 4 either ;)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                         |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1585 | This function 'checksum' has the same name as a native function |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It works with another name. Forget it!

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. But you have to call the function with back-tick delimiters so it will be interpreted as an identifier instead of a keyword.

```
mysql> select `checksum`('foobar');
+----------------------+
| `checksum`('foobar') |
+----------------------+
|           2666930069 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                         |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1585 | This function 'checksum' has the same name as a native function |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can see it still returns a warning, but at least it runs the stored function.

In general, trying to write cross-vendor SQL queries is full of exception cases like this. In my experience, it's easier to develop an [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) in your application code, so you can run *different* SQL queries for each back-end database.

Comment: Thank you also for your advice, but in my case there is no application code at all. I am exploring the creation of standalone databases which can serve as tutorials or text-based adventures to learn and practice SQL. See https://github.com/laowantong/sqlab for more details (currently not much, but there are some working examples).

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has already the name [checksum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checksum-table.html), so you need to rename your function

```
select crc32('foobar');
```

| crc32('foobar') |
| --- |
| 2666930069 |

```
CREATE FUNCTION checksum_v(x TEXT) 
  RETURNS BIGINT
  DETERMINISTIC
  BEGIN
    RETURN crc32(x);
  END;
```

```
select checksum_v('foobar');
```

| checksum_v('foobar') |
| --- |
| 2666930069 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dQOVQBpf)

Comment: Where is this function? it's not here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html, or here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=201&p=1&q=CHECKSUM

Comment: @Luuk https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checksum-table.html

Comment: hmmz, and i was looking for a "a native SQL function" .... 

Comment: Despite the warning, CHECKSUM is not a builtin function in current MySQL. It's a keyword used in other SQL syntax.